# create whmcs 6 feed to check if client is logged in

Tags: php, mysql, web, whmcs

I'am trying to check if a user is logged and display the first name from outside whmcs folder. I'am using feeds. I have created checkifloggedin.php in the feeds folder.

```
<?php
require("../init.php");    
if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {

    /*i can get the the id of the user but i cannot display the first
      name of the logged in user. tried several methods but i cannot
      make it work.*/

    widgetoutput();
    }
else {
    widgetoutput('logged out');
}

function widgetoutput($value) {
    echo "document.write('".addslashes($value)."');";
    exit;
}

?>
```

any help from you guys would be so appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to do the same thing recently, and found that a lot of the filenames/paths have changed since the older replies on this and similar questions. A word on my config - I have WHMCS setup in public_html/whmcs for all practical purposes. My index page and a few others (about, terms, etc.) are in public_html (docroot).

First thing i did was create a file called loggedin.php in public_html containing the following code:

```html
<?php

$li = 0;

// Define WHMCS namespaces
use WHMCS\ClientArea;
use WHMCS\Database\Capsule;

// Initialize WHMCS client area
define('CLIENTAREA', true);
require __DIR__ . '/whmcs/init.php';
$ca = new ClientArea();

if ($ca->isLoggedIn()) { //logged in
    $clientName = Capsule::table('tblclients')->where('id', '=', $ca->getUserID())->pluck('firstname');
    $ca->assign('clientname', $clientName);
    $li = $clientName[0];
}
else { //not logged in
    $ca->assign('clientname', 'Random User');
}

?>
```

Then, I include it in my index file:

```html
<?php include("loggedin.php"); ?>
```

And then when someone visits the homepage, if they are logged in the var $li = the first name of the logged in user, while if $li = 0 they are not logged in. I use it to dynamically render the main menu like so:

```html
<?php if ($li == "0") : ?>
        <li><a href="#" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="whmcs/register.php" role="button" class="btn btn-success">Sign Up</a></li>
<?php else : ?>
        <li><a href="whmcs/clientarea.php">Hello, <?php echo $li; ?></a></li>        
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope that helps anyone searching for a newer answer to the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to use the internal API of the WHMCS platform:
http://docs.whmcs.com/API:Internal_API

In the widget code, you would want to use something like this:

```
// Set Vars
$command = 'getclientsdetails';
$values = array( 'clientid' => $_SESSION['uid'], 'responsetype' => 'json', );
$adminuser = 'DemoAdmin';

// Call API
$results = localAPI($command, $values, $adminuser);
if ($results['result']!="success") {
    echo "An Error Occurred: ".$results['result'];
    exit;
}

$results = json_decode( $results );
```

Then $results should contain the user info you are looking for.